# How to strip out signatures and other insanity from the Outlook replies?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

The office email threads can sometimes get large.  Some people have super large signatures complete with images, links, fonts, etc... that far outstrip the actual content of the email.  Example:

[image]

In addition, the emails are littered with warning messages:
[image]

As a result, to just be able to understand what is going on is next to impossible with this type of noise to signal ratio.

Is there a way in Outlook (or with some 3rd party plugin) to strip out all this junk when I either read the email chain or press `Reply All` (to spare other people)?  Or even using an app other than Outlook.

Comment: How would you expect the software to tell where the core of the message ends and signature begins? (BTW did you check at [Software Recommendations SE?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @miroxlav The signatures are stored at the server level, therefore, the software should be able to deduce where the signature starts and ends.

Comment: – only mailbox owners' signature is available from there to Outlook, other signatures are a random text from Outlook viewpoint. Other parties' mail platofrms may have their signatures configured only in the client and they often have no server (in MS Exchange sense), just mailboxes.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Email. In the Ribbon, beside MOVE, there is a More Move Actions pull down. Pull it down, see Edit Message. Click on that, edit the message (so remove the items you wish) and then File Save.

This is a User action and users must do it as they deem appropriate